# Value Error: Substring not found from the script running path

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following code which is throwing an error: `ValueError: Substring Not Found.`

```
import os, sys
myCwd = os.path.abspath(__file__)
svtestcases = os.path.normpath('Tests/SVTestCases')
tcPath = myCwd[:myCwd.index(svtestcases) + len(svtestcases)]
sys.path.insert(0, tcPath)
```

The error is raised from the fourth line of the `myCwd.index(svtestcases)` part.

The path of the python script is : `"C:\Netra_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\TC-Regression"`

What might be the issue? Also why there is a `':'` before `myCwd.index`? Can anyone explain please?

Comment: Have you tried printing both `myCwd` and `svtestcases`?

Comment: because it won't get any integer value or there isn't an index. List slicing is used here `listname[start:end]` . Here the start is nothing, so it prints form the start upto the end index.

Comment: You need to run the file from the same directory where the directory `Tests` is located. So, copy the python file to the `C:\Netra_Step_2015` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "myCwd" and "svtestcases" doesn't have anything in common and when you try to find the index of substring "svtestcases" , it is not matched at all with your myCwd.

For e.g :

```
>>> a = '/Test/test1/test2/test3'
>>> a.index('/Test')
0
>>> a.index('test2')
12
>>> 
>>> a.index('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
>>>
```

Though the comment already mentions about it. i just added a little code to make it more easy to understand. It also tells you about the colon part.
Read more about slicing and you will find it.

Comment: kingsdeb, thank you for the example. The issue got resolved by changing SVTestCases to 'SVTestcases' because that was the actual path. But the colon is still not clear.